# Button's event listener doesn't change class field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, addeventlistener

What I am trying to do:

- a random number is generated
- a timer counts to this number and  then shows a button with a random margin
- the first timer stops, the second timer starts
- when the user clicks the button the second timer prints how much time passed between the button appearance and click

I wanted to make a component class field that is a boolean, and when the button is clicked the boolean changes to true, and then the timer at every tick checks the boolean value and if true, deletes the button and starts the first timer again.

The proble is that when I click the button, the clicked field doesn't change. What's the catch here?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TimerObservable} from "rxjs/observable/TimerObservable";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-gra',
  templateUrl: './gra.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gra.component.css']
})
export class GraComponent implements OnInit {

  randNum: any;
  timerSub: any;
  userTimerSub: any;
  clicked: boolean;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.randNum = 3+ Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    console.log('random: ' + this.randNum)
    this.clicked = false;
    let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000);
    this.timerSub = timer.subscribe( d => this.timerFunction(d) );
  }

  timerFunction(d){
    console.log(d);

    if(d === this.randNum){

      var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
      var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node

      btn.appendChild(t);
      btn.id = "button"

      let margin  = Math.floor(Math.random()*500);

      document.body.appendChild(btn);                    // Append <button> to <body>
      btn.setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: ' + margin + "px;");
      document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", this.buttonClick);

      this.timerSub.unsubscribe();

      let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000);
      this.userTimerSub = timer.subscribe( d => this.userTimerFunction(d) );
      this.randNum = 3 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
      console.log('new rand: ' + this.randNum)
    }
  }

  userTimerFunction(d){
    console.log('user' + d)
    console.log(this.clicked)
    if(this.clicked == true){
      console.log('It took you ' + d + 'seconds');

      this.userTimerSub.unsubscribe();
      var element = document. getElementById("button");
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

      let timer = TimerObservable.create(0, 1000);
      this.timerSub = timer.subscribe( d => this.timerFunction(d) );
    }
  }

  buttonClick(){
    console.log('clicked: ' + this.clicked);
    this.clicked = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that binding the click method your way will not bind the 'this' keyword the way that you expect it and the 'clicked' property will not changed. You can try to use the [fat arrow syntax to bind the 'this' keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this).

```
addEventListener("click", () => this.buttonClick())
```

However I would recommend that you use Angulars built in renderer [service for handling dom manipulations](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) if you want to work in Angular.

```
this.renderer.listen(elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (evt) => {
    console.log('Clicking the document', evt);
})
```